# Error - com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.project_sewing.Event1

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, compiler-errors

I get this error -     "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.project_sewing.Event1" on the bold title.
I create an app for queue management, I have a map of string(the phone number) and the ArrayList of all events.

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        if(key.equals("clients")) {
                            allEvents = childSnapshot.getValue(AllEvents.class);
                        } else if(key.equals("manager")) {
                            manager = childSnapshot.getValue(Manager.class);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

Here is the Event1:

```
public class Event1 {
    private String number,type,messages,hour;
    private int price,day,year,month,status;

    public Event1(String number, String type, int price, int day, int month, int year, String hour,int status, String messages) {}


    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public Event1(){}

    public void setMessages(Event1 event) {
        this.messages = "The event:" + event+ " is cancel";
    }

    public int calculationCost(){ }

      @Override
    public String toString() {}
}
```

Here is the AllEvents:

```
public class AllEvents {
    private Map<String, ArrayList<Event1>> data;

    public Map<String,ArrayList<Event1>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public AllEvents() {
         data = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Event1>>();
    }

    public void setData(Map<String,ArrayList<Event1>> data) {

        this.data = data;
    }
    public void addToList(String mapKey,Event1 event){
        ArrayList<Event1> itemsList = data.get(mapKey);
        if(itemsList == null) {
            itemsList = new ArrayList<Event1>();
            itemsList.add(event);
            data.put(mapKey, itemsList);
        } else
            if(!itemsList.contains(event)) itemsList.add(event);
    }
    public AllEvents(Map<String,ArrayList<Event1>> map) {
        if(this.data == null)
            data = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Event1>>();
        else
            this.data = map;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public boolean isExist(Event1 e)
    {
        if(!data.containsKey(e.getNumber()))
            return false;
        ArrayList<Event1> elist =  data.get(e.getNumber());
        for (Event1 eitem: elist) {
            if(eitem.equals(e))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually your `dataSnapshot` return String instead of `AllEvents`. Can you add your database structure? Also add details of `myRef`

Comment: Sure, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8ACf.png @Md. Asaduzzaman 3

Comment: Can you also add `myRef` and `AllEvents` model?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your **database** structure, You are getting multiple `children` from your `query` to **firebase**. You have to handle this like below:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        String key = childSnapshot.getKey();

        if(key.equals("clients")) {
            allEvents = childSnapshot.getValue(AllEvents.class);
        } else if(key.equals("manager")) {
            manager = childSnapshot.getValue(Manager.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Also change your `Event1` like below:

```
public class Event1 {
    private String number,type,messages,hour;
    private int price,day,year,month,status;

    public Event1(String number, String type, int price, int day, int month, int year, String hour,int status, String messages) {}


    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public Event1(){}

    public int calculationCost(){ }

    @Override
    public String toString() {}
}
```

Comment: I get a null from this database structure

Comment: Now I get this database structure: message->clients->data->data. It didn't work when I tried to read from the firebase. @Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: I create an app for queue management, I have a map of string(the phone number) and the ArrayList of all events

Comment: Can you add full code of `AllEvents` and `Event1`?

Comment: I added the full code, thanks! @ Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: Besides this, You will not get all data of **Event1** unless you implement **getter** for all the property. Currently you only get `number`

Comment: Thank you for the help! @Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: I don't understand your answer before..

Comment: What I need to change to?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I missed your code, still the same problem. @Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: I have updated the code, I apply your code and I get the same error-    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.project_sewing.Event1

Comment: Your `Event1` model have some problems. I remove one. Now try with updated code

Comment: It works! thank you very math!!!